# Unsuccessful $rename'ing a field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3, and trying to rename a field from shell.

Here's the exact command:

`db.deals.update({},{$rename:{'deal':'object'}},{multi:true})`

It returns:

`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 18, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`

It appears fine, but actually the collection structure remains intact after the command.

Comment: Sounds like there are no fields named "deal". Is this perhaps embedded in a sub-document or array?

Comment: @NeilLunn but `"nMatched" : 18` in result suggests otherwise.
The same result is returned every time I execute the command.

Comment: @NeilLunn, yeah, sorry, "nMatched"  is for first part- `{}`

Comment: nMatched just means exactly that yes. Your field does not exist or at least not at this level. Your document added to your question should make this clear but it seems really just to be a simple mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to perform the `$rename` multiple times. The empty query to match `{}`--the first parameter to update will match all documents in the collection (the reason you are getting `nMatched=18`). However, you are getting `nModified:0` because there were no documents having field called `deal`. See the example below:

```
> db.deals.remove({})
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })
> db.deals.insert({"deal":"test"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.deals.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53abfc1277e9b67082836948"), "deal" : "test" }
> db.deals.update({},{$rename:{'deal':'object'}},{multi:true})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.deals.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53abfc1277e9b67082836948"), "object" : "test" }
>
```

You can easily check if you have any documents containing `deal`:

```
db.deals.find({'deal':{$exists:true}})
```

Comment: The `$exists` check here would actually not make any difference. The clear problem is that the field does not exist at all at the root level anywhere. If it does not, then the operator does nothing. As the poster already found out.

Comment: @NeilLunn you are of course right, I edited the answer.

Comment: I'm just giving you a heads up that despite those people who up-voted, this is not actually the answer. The problem is that the document just does not contain the field being asked for at that path in the `$rename` operation. I wouldn't count on those up-votes hanging around forever. But then again, the question is basically just a typo and misunderstanding.

Comment: Yeah @NeilLunn, it was a typo. I've tried to delete the question but SO doesn't allow me. That's why I've flagged it for moderator attention.